# Laravel migration from 5.6 to 5.8 and now all url links don't work

Tags: php, laravel

I just updated carbon and laravel framework from 5.6 to 5.8.35 and now my links on my pages won't fire so I can't go from one page to another, but my pages load with templates and data on the page route. I'm running my laravel project through a virtual host so my domain name is http://myproject.local/, I'm using wamp server and created a virtual host, has something changed in the htaccess file do I need to add a rewrite rule, does anyone have suggestions as to get my links working, your help would be appreciated thank you

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have you tried updating all the composer packages? I don't think there's a breaking change

Comment: I have reverted to my old app and now none of my links work at all

Comment: @ONYX Where is your `.htaccess` file location in your project? Your .htaccess file all code is valid